# Boost ASIO bind: Invalid argument

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, udp, boost-asio

I am trying to bind an endpoint to a socket and I receive such exception

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >'
  what():  bind: Invalid argument
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The code is as following. I prefer to solve the problem of binding.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;

int main()
{
    const int port=2405;
    const std::string ip="127.0.0.1";

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    udp::endpoint endpoint;
    udp::socket socket(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), 0));

    udp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    endpoint = *resolver.resolve({udp::v4(), ip, std::to_string(port)});
    socket.bind(endpoint);

    return 0;
}
```

make:

```
g++ test.cpp -Wfatal-errors -o test -std=c++11 -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_serialization -pthread
```

Comment: The dubious TCP 'shortcut' you mention does not apply to this UDP code.

Comment: @EJP, I fixed the term. In the alternative method, the solution has avoided using `bind`. Despite I use `UDP`, I do not see any fundamental difference. Is it possible to bind to a specific IP in UDP?

Comment: Of course it is possible to bind in UDP. Otherise it would be useless. I'm curious about passing the port number as a string. Is that really correct? The workaround you mentioned appears to consist of passing an extra optional argument to `accept()`, which has no relevance in UDP, and isn't necessary in TCP either. There's nothing there about not binding. A TCP server that didn't bind would also be completely useless.

Comment: @EJP, using `int` gives me compiler error. Please search for `*resolver.resolve` in [this boost example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/blocking_udp_echo_client.cpp). It has used string too.

Comment: OK. Doesn't explain the relevance of your 'shortcut' though.